# Efficiently group by column aggregate

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica, vsql

```
SELECT date, id, sum(revenue)
FROM table
WHERE date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-08'
GROUP BY date, id
HAVING sum(revenue)>1000
```

Returns rows that have revenue>1000.

```
SELECT date, id, sum(revenue)
FROM table
WHERE date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-08'
AND id IN (SELECT id FROM table where date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-08' GROUP BY id HAVING sum(revenue)>1000)
GROUP BY date, id
```

Returns rows for id's whose total revenue over the date period is >1000 as desired. But this query is much slower. Any quicker way to do this?

Comment: How about some `EXPLAIN` first?

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong does these queries return different results ???

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have indexes on the `date` and `id` columns, and try this variation:

```
select t.date, t.id, sum(t.revenue)
from table t
inner join (
    select id
    from table
    where date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-08'
    group by id
    having sum(revenue) > 1000
) ts on t.id = ts.id
where t.date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-08'
group by t.date, t.id
```

Comment: Modern mysql optimizer would produce the same (or *very similar*) execution plan for both of them

Comment: Btw, op needs not *indexes* but a single composite `(date, id)` index. Or even may be `(date, id, revenue)` index, it worth trying as well

Comment: @zerkms - Your composite index would not help the inner `GROUP BY` or the `JOIN`, though, which is just on `id`. This is splitting hairs, though, which indexes are really best depend on the data, and need real-world testing. My suggestion was a guideline, not an absolute.

Comment: separate indexes wouldn't help either. PS: There is a chance to optimize it anyway using `date IN ('2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', ...)`. That way `(date, id)` index *might be* used (since it's not a range comparison anymore)

Comment: @RedFilter I tried your solution, and it was slower. My original solution took on average 11s, yours 19s. Does this mean that date and id are likely not indexed? Also one possible variable is that I'm querying a Vertica database (not mysql). So although the syntax is largely the same--maybe the processing behind the scenes is different?

Comment: Apparently Vertica doesn't support indexes, you have to use projections: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#12037.htm

Comment: I only have read privileges, so it looks like my hands are tied.

Answer (score 1):

it's not MySQL, it's Vertica ;)

Cris, what projection and `order by` you using in `CREATE TABLE` ???

Do you try using `database designer` 
see http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#14415.htm